# Have a select box filled with names

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

In my view I have a form with a text_field_tag that takes an int, and returns only the timesheets whose timesheet.user_id match that int

```
<%= text_field_tag("user_id", params[:user_id]) %>
```

And then I have a bunch of users, these users have a name `user.name` and an id `user.id`.

I have a method in the controller called pending_approvals that when given the user id, narrows my list down to a specific users objects.

```
if params[:user_id].present?
  @time_sheets = @time_sheets.joins(:user).where("users.id IN (?)", params[:user_id])
end
```

So what I am having an issue with, is I am not sure how to populate my select box with a list of users names. And then when submitted I need it to give the users id to that method. What is the best way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly is you want a collection dropdown list to detail all users and thier id. You can do:

```
<%= collection_select :user, :user_id, @users, :name, :id, :prompt => true %>
```

Where :text_method is method which called on @users members will return text that you'd like to appear in dropdown.

The [ApiDocs](http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.13/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/collection_select) breaks it down, and this is how it is set up:

```
object = User
method = user_id 
collection @users 
value_method = id 
text_method = name 
option = prompt => true
```

Comment: @Elementmindfreak its a ruby injection that acts a form helper when making your form you don't necessarily have to have this as this is mainly for the actual form which can also be seen here http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#option-tags-from-a-collection-of-arbitrary-objects

Comment: I tried the first one without the .f and I got undefined method `map' for :name:Symbol

Comment: when you say tried the first one? Is this on the link i provided you? That uses the cities_array ?

Comment: no this `<%= collection_select :user_id, @users, :name, :text_method, :prompt => true %>`

Comment: Another thing did you say that a user belongs to a timesheet?

Comment: They are both separate objects, it is just that the timesheets have a property, `timesheet.user_id` that shows which `user.id` made it.

Comment: with   `<%= form_tag({}, class: "form-inline") do %>
 <%= label_tag("employee_names", "Employees") %>
 <%= collection_select :user_id, @users, :name, :id, :prompt => true %>` I get undefined method `map' for :name:Symbol

Comment: @Elementmindfreak see my update, was missing the value method